# Azure Devops - use a script to access the number of build validation pipelines in a Pull Request

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-powershell

i want to access the number of build validation pipeline checks in a Pull Request(PR).
I was hoping i could use powershell in integrate the azure api i.e.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/get-pull-request?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0

This doesn't seem to have this information.
Does anyone know if this can be achieved?

[image: devpos pull request build validation checks]

Comment: AzDO is a SAP application. In the navigator console, you can retrieve all requests do by the client.

Comment: Seem the build validation information under this endpoint : `POST http://azuredevops.pasquier.loc:8080/tfs/SI/_apis/Contribution/dataProviders/query/project/{project-guid}`. It's a private endpoint. More information on this [post](http://www.bryancook.net/2022/01/invoking-azure-devops-hidden-rest-api.html)

Comment: @Paul Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can meet your requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to access the number of build validation pipeline checks in a Pull Request(PR).

To meet your requirement, you can use the Rest API: [Evaluations - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/policy/evaluations/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) to get the number of the builds in a Pull Request.

Here is an example:

**Rest API URL:**

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/policy/evaluations?artifactId={artifactId}&api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

**ArtifactID sample:**

```
vstfs:///CodeReview/CodeReviewId/{projectId}/{pullRequestId}
```

PowerShell sample:

```
$token = "PAT"

$url=" https://dev.azure.com/ORGNAME/PROJECTNAME/_apis/policy/evaluations?artifactId=vstfs:///CodeReview/CodeReviewId/projectid/pullrequestid&api-version=7.1-preview.1"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get  -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"}   -ContentType 'application/json'

$number = 0

Foreach( $configurationlist in $response.value )
{
   $buildid =  $configurationlist.configuration.settings.buildDefinitionId
   $type = $configurationlist.configuration.type.displayName

   if($type -eq "Build")

    {
       echo $buildid
       $number= $number+ 1
    }   
 
   

}


echo "Pull Request Build Number: $number"
```

**Result:**

[image]